# How to display contents using while loop and then exclude a comma at the end ?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in displaying content, it use "while" loop

```
<?php
    $mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;


            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );



        echo "{image : '$image[0];'},";

    endwhile;
?>
```

But what I want to achieve is, to remove the comma of the last loop so for example I have a 3 stuff to loop then the scenario should be like this.

```
{image : 'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/image1.jpg'},
{image : 'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/image2.jpg'},
{image : 'http://website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/image3.jpg'}
```

as you can see at the third loop the comma was removed, that's what I am  trying to achieve. But so far I have no idea how to make that.

I am open in any suggestion, recommendation and ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$images = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

       $images[] = "{image : '<?php echo get_option('slider3_Field');?>'}";

endwhile;

echo implode(',', $images);
```

Comment: If you want to do it in PHP only, this is the most correct way. (Though, separating is better.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use it as JSON, right? Why not separate your PHP from your JS?

```
$images = array();
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

  $images[] = (object) array('image' => wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0]);

endwhile;

echo json_encode($images);
```

Comment: much cleaner solution

Comment: @JuliverGalleto, my answer doesn't really change.

Answer (score 0):

instead of echo have your tried savins as a variable i.e.

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

        $str .= "{image : '<?php echo get_option('slider3_Field');?>'},";

    endwhile;

rtrim($str,',');

echo $str;
```